# Am tried to get divs between two specific divs using selenium and python

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

from the html below i want to get divs between div1 and div two, I need help figuring out a way that i can get the divs with selenium

```
 <div class="div"></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div class="div2"></div>
```

this is the code is used

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('.//div[@class="div1"]').find_elements_by_xpath('//following::div')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If You want to get the divs between

```
div class div1
```

and

```
div class div2
```

Please use below XPath

```
.//div[@class='div1']//following-sibling::div[not(@class='div2')]
```

In your code, something like this :

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('.//div[@class="div1"]').find_elements_by_xpath(".//div[@class='div1']//following-sibling::div[not(@class='div2')]")
```

to test this I created a dummy HTML,

[image]

As you can see, it is highlighting the 4 nodes.

Trust this helps!

Answer (score 0):

In your case css selector would be a better solution:

```
const cssSelector = ".div ~ div:not(.div2 ~ *):not(.div2)"
```

Basically what it does is:

```
.div ~ // selects siblings

div:not(.div2 ~ *):not(.div2) // selects all div tags expect ones that are after .div2 and .div2 itself
```

You can try it using:

```
document.querySelectorAll(".div ~ div:not(.div2 ~ *):not(.div2)");
```

Comment: Why is this beter?

Comment: If you can make XPath path expression that is shorter than cssSelector that i provided (for your particular case) i would then say that XPath solution is better.